# Try-Catch-Continue in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, try-catch

I was wondering if a try-catch-continue construct exists with the .NET framework. Now, I understand that some may look down on exception ignoring, but I believe this to be a valid case.

I am currently doing some reporting using `Telerik Reporting` and there are some fields that I choose to manually override for aesthetics. The issue is, I *don't care* whether these columns exist or not. But, if they do, I would like the change to be made. Here's a snippet:

```
Public Overrides Sub BaseStyles()
    MyBase.BaseStyles()

    Try
        GetHeader("Employee Name").Width = Unit.Cm(3.2R)
        GetFields("Some Field").Width = Unit.Cm(2.7R)
        GetFields("Employee Name").Style.TextAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left
    Catch ex As Exception
        Trace.TraceError("Columns do not exist. Message: " + ex.Message)
        ' Continue Try
    End Try

    AddStyles(TableFieldRules(), ReportAttributes.FIELDS)
    AddStyles(TableHeaderRules(), ReportAttributes.HEADERS)
    AddStyles(FieldConditionalRule(), ReportAttributes.FIELDS)
End Sub
```

Now imagine, that I have 5+ `GetHeader` or `GetField` calls. Am I going to wrap each within it's own try-catch block (or if statement)? It would be nice to log the missing column and move on, but the execution of the code within the block is *irrelevant* to the overall product.

Comment: If you don't throw anything in the catch, it will continue the code as usual... But you're best option would be to have an if statement before that looks if the columns exists. If you really want to, create a function GetHeaderOrDummyHeader that would return a dummy header if none are found.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had considered the dummy header prior, but wanted to make sure that this construct didn't exist before I went ahead with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There's no *"try-catch-continue"* statement in vb.net.

<sub>**Option 1**</sub>

However, what you *can do* is to create a list of actions.

```
Dim actions As New Dictionary(Of String, Action(Of String))

'Single-line:

actions.Add("ColumnName1", Sub(name) GetHeader(name).Width = Unit.Cm(1.0R))

actions.Add("ColumnName2", Sub(name) GetHeader(name).Width = Unit.Cm(2.0R))

actions.Add("ColumnName3", Sub(name) GetHeader(name).Width = Unit.Cm(5.0R))

'Multi-line:

actions.Add("ColumnName4", Sub(name)
                               GetHeader(name).Width = Unit.Cm(3.0R)
                               GetFields(name).Width = Unit.Cm(8.0R)
                               GetFields(name).Style.TextAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left
                           End Sub)
```

Then you iterate the list and invoke each action inside a try/catch block.

```
For Each item In actions
    Try
        item.Value.Invoke(item.Key)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Trace.TraceError(String.Format("The column '{0}' do not exist.", item.Key))
    End Try
Next
```

<sub>**Option 2**</sub>

Create a method with optional nullable parameters.

```
Public Sub SetColumnStyle(name As String, Optional width As Double? = Nothing, Optional tAlign As TextAlign? = Nothing)
    Try
        If (width.HasValue) Then
            GetHeader(name).Width = width.Value
        End If
        If (tAlign.HasValue) Then
            GetFields(name).Style.TextAlign = tAlign.Value
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Trace.TraceError(String.Format("The column '{0}' do not exist.", name))
    End Try
End Sub
```

```
SetColumnStyle("ColumnName1", tAlign:=HorizontalAlign.Left)
```

Comment: Very nice approach, I especially like option 2. It has given me a few ideas on how to keep the block concise without resorting to unconventional methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this using Anonymous methods

```
Public Sub DoThings()
    IgnoreException(Sub()
                        'Any code in here will have exceptions ignored and execution will continue after this block
                        'Do things with field1
                    End Sub)

    IgnoreException(Sub()
                        'Do things with field2
                    End Sub)

    IgnoreException(Sub()
                        'Do things with field3
                    End Sub)

    IgnoreException(Sub() Console.Write(CStr(Nothing))) 'single line example
    IgnoreException(Sub() Console.WriteLine("Even though an exception was thronw by the previous line, this line still executes"))

End Sub


Private Sub IgnoreException(action As Action)
    Try
        action.Invoke()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'ignore exceptions
        'Log the exception if you want
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I don't use a lot of VB so some of this syntax might be off
Just call this 5 times with various columns

```
Public void Sub StyleMe(string colname, Decimal w1, Decimal w2)
    Try
        GetHeader(colname).Width = Unit.Cm(w1)
        GetFields(colname).Width = Unit.Cm(w2)
        GetFields(colname).Style.TextAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left
    Catch ex As Exception
        Trace.TraceError("Columns do not exist. Message: " + ex.Message)
        ' Continue After Here
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I agree with what you are getting at, the only draw back is that the styling is not static, Each header/field may have it's style, width, height, text etc changed differently. So I would need a function for each possible property change.

Comment: You can't pass TextAlign?

Comment: Put it this way. Sometimes, I change the width, other times I change the height. At times I may change the text and others just the alignment. I may even want to do all of this, in addition to *any* other property available to the `TextBox` class provided.